# ASP NET Core 3.1 how to post FormData

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I am not able to post form data with fetch and asp.net core 3.1

I'm using fetch on the front end:

```
    handleSave(event) {        
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.target);
        fetch('Project/Edit', {
              method: 'POST',
              body: data,
              headers: !token ? {} :
                {
                  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
              }).then((response) => response.json())
    }
```

I have tried setting the Content-Type to multipart/form-data and i have also tried not having a content type.
The server side method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit([FromForm]Project project)
{
```

I have also tried

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(Project project)
{
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit([FromBody]Project project)
{
```

and

```
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult Edit([FromForm]Project project)
{
```

The project parameter is never populated.  Actually this method is never hit.  I'm receiving a 405 error.
What is the correct way to post FormData to the server with ASP.NET Core 3.1?

I ended up getting this to work with the following:
Controller - changed Edit to EditProject and added Route decorator:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("EditProject")]
public IActionResult EditProject([FromForm]Project project)
{
```

I removed the content-type from the fetch:

```
fetch('Project/EditProject', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      headers: !this.state.token ? {} :
      {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.state.token}`,
      }
   }).then((response) => response.json())
```

Comment: Fei Han's answer got me headed in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> not able to post form data with fetch and asp.net core 3.1

Here is a working sample of posting form data from React front end to API action, you can refer to it.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        pname: "",
        description: ""
    };

    this.handlePname = this.handlePname.bind(this);
    this.handleDescription = this.handleDescription.bind(this);
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
}

handlePname(event) {
    this.setState({ pname: event.target.value });
}

handleDescription(event) {
    this.setState({ description: event.target.value });
}

handleSave(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("pname", this.state.pname);
    data.append("description", this.state.description);

    console.log(data);

    fetch("Project/Edit", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
        // headers: !token
        //   ? {}
        //   : {
        //       Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        //       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        //     }
    }).then(response => response.json());
}

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSave}>
            Project Name:
            <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.pname}
                onChange={this.handlePname}
            />
            Description:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleDescription} />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
);
}
```

Controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit([FromForm]Project project)
{
    //code logic here
```

Project class

```
public class Project
{
    public string pname { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Test result

[image]

Comment: this is not working for me. I'm receiving a 405 error.  The error displayed in the browser is Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input